# QScrollArea in Qml: Flickable + QQuickPaintedItem

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, qscrollarea

I'm trying to realize something similiar to `QScrollArea` (in widgets world) with the help of Qml.
I decided to probe `Flickable` plus `QQuickPaintedItem` based item (named Drawer in my case):

```
Flickable {
  ...
  onContentXChanged(): {
  drawer.update()
  }

Drawer {
  id: drawer
  ...
}
```

Drawer's render target is set to `FrameBufferObject`. Its paint function looks like this:

```
void Drawer::paint(QPainter *painter)
{
   // Some function to compute rect which is needed to be redrawn
   QRect updateRect = computeUpdateRect();

   // How to shift contents of Frame buffer, e.g. to right, and draw only updateRect in this space?
}
```

Imagine how we do scrolling in `QScrollArea` widget, e.g. to left: all entry of viewport is shifted to right and the only small rect in left is redrawn.
I want to do the same with `Flickable`+`QQuickPaintedItem`. But I can't understand some things:

How can I manipulate Frame Buffer object inside `QQuickPaintedItem`?
Maybe there is some more right way to implement `QScrollArea` in QML?

By the way, is double buffering enabled by default in `QQuickPaintedItem`?

For implementing with `Flickable`:
To provide more info about task: I have a very big "picture". So I cannot load it whole into memory, but I have to navigate through it with something like viewport.

Comment: `QQuickPaintedItem` works with `QPainter`. Not the best idea in terms of speed so I advice you to use `QQuickItem` and work directly with OpenGL. Anyway if you use `QQuickPaintedItem` you can set `QQuickPaintedItem::setRenderTarget(QQuickPaintedItem::FramebufferObject)` and so _QPainter paints into a QOpenGLFramebufferObject using the GL paint engine_ (from the Qt docs)

Comment: @folibis Thanks for response, do you know if there's a way of manual manipulating with this framebuffer or it's accessible only through QPainter interface? I haven't found info about it in doc.

Answer (score 2):

A scroll area or a flickable are used when you want to encapsulate a larger content in a smaller area and navigate around it. And in your case that is... not the case. You are not practically using a scroll area as your image is never larger than the scroll area size, you just want to fake it, which is actually quite easy:

```
#include <QQuickPaintedItem>
#include <QImage>
#include <QPainter>

class PImage : public QQuickPaintedItem {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    PImage(QQuickItem * p = 0) : QQuickPaintedItem(p), xpos(0), ypos(0) {}
    void paint(QPainter *painter) {
        if (!source.isNull()) painter->drawImage(QRect(0, 0, width(), height()), source, QRect(xpos, ypos, width(), height()));
        else painter->fillRect(QRect(0, 0, width(), height()), Qt::black);
    }
public slots:
    bool load(QString path) {
        source = QImage(path);
        return !source.isNull();
    }
    void moveBy(int x, int y) {
        int ox, oy;
        // don't go outside the image
        ox = x + xpos + width() <= source.width() ? x + xpos : source.width() - width();
        oy = y + ypos + height() <= source.height() ? y + ypos : source.height() - height();
        if (ox < 0) ox = 0;
        if (oy < 0) oy = 0;
        if (ox != xpos || oy != ypos) {
            xpos = ox;
            ypos = oy;
            update();
        }
    }
private:
    QImage source;
    int xpos, ypos;
};
```

And on the QML side:

```
PImage {
    width: 300
    height: 300
    Component.onCompleted: load("d:/img.jpg") // a big image
    MouseArea {
        property int ix
        property int iy
        anchors.fill: parent
        onPressed: {
            ix = mouseX
            iy = mouseY
        }
        onPositionChanged: {
            parent.moveBy(ix - mouseX, iy - mouseY)
            ix = mouseX
            iy = mouseY
        }
    }
}
```

This is just a quick basic example, there is a lot of room to polish and improve. Also note that if the source rect is different size than the target rect, you can easily achieve zooming in or out. You can hook it to a flickable to get the "kinetic scrolling" instead of the mouse area.

Comment: added info about task: I have a very big "picture". So I cannot load it whole into memory, but I have to navigate through it with something like viewport.

Comment: So what does `QScrollArea` have to do with it? It doesn't support partial image loading. How big is the picture? What format is the picture? Does it even support partial loading?

Comment: Thanks for response, by "picture" I meant a scalable canvas (size may be more than 10 000 x 10 000 pxs), parts of which can be drawn dynamically.

Comment: A 10k x 10k RGBA image would only take like 380 MB of ram. And besides, if it is a canvas, then it will be in ram anyway. It is still not clear what you want to do. If all you need is to draw a rectangular region of a larger image, then just use `void QPainter::drawImage(const QRect & rectangle, const QImage & image)`

Comment: exactly, consider you've flicked view and want to draw only region that has updated (but not the whole screen) .

Comment: @Sas - check the answer revision

Comment: Thanks for clear basic example! One moment: if we change QImage source with computationally expensive procedure to get update image: it'll take a long time to update whole region all the time.  In this case are we needed to realize double buffering in c++ or there is some way to do it with Qt Quick. (I've read Qt doc but it's still not clear to me).

Comment: @Sas - don't concern yourself with premature optimizations. Do it only after you establish that there is indeed a performance problem. The scenegraph itself probably uses double buffering. Consider offloading the operation from the main to a worker thread to keep the main thread responsive.