# Display and refresh an image in QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I don't understand how to display an image in QML with `QQuickPaintedItem` class (or maybe another method ?).

My program is currently displaying it using `QImage` and an ImageProvider, it works but randomly crashed so I would like to try another method.

Moreover, the image should be refreshed each time a new frame is transmitted.

I get the information from an `uchar` raw data but I don't see how to paint from raw data.

Moreover a new raw data is coming at approximately 60 fps so the QML need to refresh the image at this rate.

EDIT :

Other parts of the code :

My class is :

```
class StreamPainter : public QQuickPaintedItem
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    StreamPainter(QQuickItem *p = 0):QQuickPaintedItem(p){}
    ~StreamPainter();

    void paint(QPainter *painter){painter->drawImage(QPoint(0, 0), _streamImage);}


public slots:
    void onImageAvailable(QImage image) {
        _streamImage = image;
        update();
private:
    QImage _streamImage;

};
```

In main :

for the invalid property name, it was due to the import StreamPainter 1.0, seems it didn't like that name since it was consfused, I've changed it to myModule and  the error disappeared.

```
qmlRegisterType<StreamPainter>("myModule", 1, 0, "StreamPainter");
```

Creation of the object and of the thread :

```
streamImage = new StreamPainter();
myPipeThread = new PipeThread(streamImage);
```

Thread constructor :

```
PipeThread::PipeThread(StreamPainter* spvideostr)
:QThread(),
 _namedPipe(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE),
 _spvideostr(spvideostr),
 _abort(false),
 _rawData(NULL)
{
    ...
}
```

Thread class, I've added :

```
signals:
    void imageAvailable(QImage image);
```

Then in my thread, I do the connect and in the while I create the QImage and emit the signal :

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(imageAvailable(QImage)), _spvideostr, SLOT(onImageAvailable(QImage)));

while(...)
    QImage clImage(_rawData, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT,     QImage::Format_Indexed8);
    emit imageAvailable(clImage);
```

QML :

```
import QtQuick 2.0

import MyModule 1.0

StreamPainter {

    width : 100 
    height : 100
```

Comment: Don't you want to fix the crash instead? Anyway using QQuickPaintedItem for just showing image is overkill at least. Besides the fact that isn't declarative way.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I refresh an Image in QML with a function inside the component like this:

```
Image {
                id: imageLogo
                cache: false
                anchors.fill: parent
                //anchors.leftMargin: 20
                Layout.preferredWidth: Math.round(parent.width / 1.5)
                Layout.preferredHeight: Math.round(parent.height * 2)

                function reloadImage() {
                    var oldSource = source
                    source = ""
                    source = oldSource
                }//function to refresh the source

            }
```

And then I only call this function wherever you want to reload the image

```
imageLogo.reloadImage()
```

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple, all you have to do is draw the image in the `paint()` method:

```
void paint(QPainter *painter) {
    painter->drawImage(QPoint(0, 0), yourImage);
}
```

Then call `update()` every time `yourImage` changes.

Don't draw raw data, create a `QImage` from it with the proper format and draw that. You can use the static method `QImage fromData(const uchar *data, int size, const char *format = Q_NULLPTR)`. Since `QImage` is an implicitly shared object, you can efficiently `yourImage = QImage::fromData(...)` and then `update()` every time you get new data.

EDIT:

You should be creating the object in QML. Also, seeing how you use threads, keep in mind UI elements can only be accessed from the main thread. This means that you can't do this:

```
_spvideostr->setStreamImage(clImage);
_spvideostr->update();
```

as you are accessing a UI object from another thread. Instead you should use a signal and slot with a queued connection, pass the image through that connection, and set the image and call `update()` from the slot of `StreamPainter`.

You don't need that:

```
Q_PROPERTY(QImage streamImage READ streamImage WRITE setStreamImage NOTIFY streamImageChanged)
```

This image will only be accessed from that class. So you don't need those either:

```
QImage streamImage();
void setStreamImage(QImage clImage);

signals:
    void streamImageChanged(QImage Image);
```

What you need there is a:

```
public slots:
    void onImageAvaiable(QImage image) { ...set image and call update }
```

In `PipeThread` you need a signal `void imageAvaiable(QImage)`, connect `imageAvaiable` to `onImageAvaiable` and emit the image:

```
QImage clImage(_rawData, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
emit imageAvaiable(clImage);
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that.

But on the QML part how do I display it ?
Do I have to use update there or Rendertarget ?

Comment: Just create an instance of the object. Take a look at this answer, it is a little more complicated than your problem, but it covers everything you need : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35460369/qscrollarea-in-qml-flickable-qquickpainteditem/35671552#35671552

Comment: @Dinendal - your item current has a size of 0x0... give it some width and height.

Comment: Yes, I have an invalid property name. Do I have to declare a Q_Property for each of them ?

Comment: Are you inheriting `QQuickPaintedItem`? It declares those properties.

Comment: I have edited the first post with the class, the registertype in main and creation of the object and thread.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try.
@ddriver
I've added for onImageAvailable :

`_streamImage = image;
        this->update();`  

And the connect is :
`connect(_spvideostr, SIGNAL(imageAvailable(QImage)), _spvideostr, SLOT(onImageAvailable(QImage)));`  I'm not sure here if I have to do a link with qml, I still have black window

Comment: @Dinendal - no, I've written `In PipeThread you need a signal void imageAvaiable(QImage)`, pay attention ;) Also, you don't need the `this` in `this->update()`. The connection will detect that the two objects live in different threads and use `Qt::QueuedConnection`, although you can specify it manually as well as the last parameter in the `connec()`

Comment: Ah ok, sorry.
I've created the signal in the PipeThread class and did the connect : `connect(this, SIGNAL(imageAvailable(QImage)), _spvideostr, SLOT(onImageAvailable(QImage)));` QML is : `StreamPainter {
    width : 800
    height : 800
` but still I have a no images

Comment: OK a few other hints - 1 don't subclass `QThread` instead create a `QObject` based worker and move it to a new `QThread`, 2 - do the connection from the main thread, 3 - put debug statements in your code to see where you are and what get executed and what doesn't.

Comment: I've tried displaying some colors, it works, but I can't update it. It only display the color given at the initialilization of the class

Comment: As I said, try to make the connection from the main thread. When you create the painter and the thread, connect them immediately after that.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved refreshing an image in QML by binding the `source` property of an `Image` to a **url** to which I tacked on an arbitrary **query string** and simply changed the value in that appended part of the image location using an auto incrementing counter each time the value is retrieved.

Roughly, something like this (from the C Side):

```
QString imageURL()
{
    static const QString QUERY_STRING_KEY( "?refresh=" );
    static ushort imageRefreshCounter( 0 );
    return imageUrl_ +
        QUERY_STRING_KEY + QString::number( ++imageRefreshCounter );
}
```

This function would be fired off implicitly via a [Q_PROPERTY](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_PROPERTY) when some signal is emitted (e.g. `emit imageChanged();`) which triggers a QML binding refresh.

Doing this, there is no need to change the name of the actual image, or play a game with clearing and resetting the source property on the QML side.

Note: depending on how you want write this in your own project, you might opt to further abstract this, use a literal QUrl, and call upon its [setQuery](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qurl.html#setQuery-1) method.  I'm showing this here with raw strings just to keep it a bit more simple/straightforward.